# Mirror the incoming data from one COM port to a virtual COM port on Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

Is there a way that two drivers are connected to the same COM device with one being able to send data to the device and both receiving the incoming data?

In more detail:
Both drivers also want to send data to the device, which causes problems if both have write access to the device. Therefore a symlink to a virtual COM port doesn't help at all.

So I guess the best option would be to mirror all the incoming data from the device to a virtual COM port. One driver is connected to the real device (therefore also being able to send data to the device). The other one is only connected to the virtual COM port and therefore all data sent by this program should end up in /dev/null.

Is there a way of doing this or are there even better solutions?

**EDIT**: Some approaches by now:

1. Using socat

   ```
   sudo socat pty,link=/dev/modem0,raw,waitslave file:/dev/ttyACM0,nonblock
   ```

   Doesn't work since it's a symlink.
2. Using tee

   ```
   sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0 | tee 1.txt 2.txt /dev/modem0
   ```

   Isn't able to write to (virtual) COM ports (/dev/modem0 fails) AND I don't get a direct connection in order to also send data to ttyACM0
3. Using slsnif (isn't compatible to current kernels)
4. Using interceptty

   ```
   sudo interceptty /dev/ttyACM0 -o "1.txt"
   ```

   Is only able to sniff ASCII-Characters, all binary data is lost in the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application that opens this port and distributes the data to several file descriptor, something like [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee).

Comment: See my edit. Tee is a good idea in principle, but there are several problems. 
1) By using it I loose the opportunity to also send data to the port 
2) It can't send the data to virtual COM ports

Comment: Then you need to write an application that syncs the writes to the TTY.

Comment: Well, once I'm reading from the COM port with one application I can't use another application to write to it. So problem 1 can't be addressed by doing so.